# How to Implement a Bitset in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

The below code, which creates and uses a bitset, is from the following tutorial ["Intro to Bit Vectors"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYoJ6gUXZvc). I am rewriting this code to try to learn and understand more about C structs and pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORDSIZE 32
#define BITS_WORDSIZE 5
#define MASK 0x1f

// Create a bitset
int initbv(int **bv, int val) {
  *bv = calloc(val/WORDSIZE + 1, sizeof(int));
  return *bv != NULL;
}

// Place int 'i' in the biset
void set(int bv[], int i) {
  bv[i>>BITS_WORDSIZE] |= (1 << (i & MASK));
}

// Return true if integer 'i' is a member of the bitset
int member(int bv[], int i) {
  int boolean = bv[i>>BITS_WORDSIZE] & (1 << (i & MASK));
  return boolean;
}

int main() {
  int *bv, i;

  int s1[] = {32, 5, 0};
  int s2[] = {32, 4, 5, 0};

  initbv(&bv, 32);

  // Fill bitset with s1
  for(i = 0; s1[i]; i++) {
    set(bv, s1[i]);
  }

  // Print intersection of bitset (s1) and s2
  for(i = 0; s2[i]; i++) {
    if(member(bv, s2[i])) {
      printf("%d\n", s2[i]);
    }
  }

  free(bv);
  return 0;
}
```

Below, is what I have rewritten to make use of structs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORDSIZE 32
#define BITS_WS 5
#define MASK 0x1f

struct bitset {
  int *bv;
};

/* Create bitset that can hold 'size' items */
struct bitset * bitset_new(int size) {
  struct bitset * set = malloc(sizeof(struct bitset));

  set->bv = calloc(size/WORDSIZE + 1, sizeof(int));

  return set;
}

/* Add an item to a bitset */
int bitset_add(struct bitset * this, int item) {
  return this->bv[item>>BITS_WS] |= (1 << (item & MASK));
}

/* Check if an item is in the bitset */
int bitset_lookup(struct bitset * this, int item) {
 int boolean = this->bv[item>>BITS_WS] & (1 << (item & MASK));
  printf("%d\n", boolean);
  return boolean;
}

int main() {
  struct bitset * test = bitset_new(32);

  int num = 5;
  bitset_add(test, num);

  printf("%d\n", bitset_lookup(test, num));

  return 0;
}
```

What I have rewritten is not working as expected. To test the implementation, in main() I try a bitset_lookup and expect a return value of 0 or 1 but I get a value of 32. I believe it must be something to do with my use of pointers, although I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This is where a debugger can help.

Comment: 1) Don't use signed integers for bitshifts/masking if you are not aware of the negative implications. 2) use fixed-width types if you wantr fixed with. 3) There is no relation between `WORDSIZE` and `sizeof(int)`. 4) If that is from that toturial, forget about it and get a better one ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a tutorial, it is misleading examples at best.

First of all, use an unsigned type. I recommend `unsigned long` (for various reasons, none of them critical). The `<limits.h>` header file defines constant `CHAR_BIT`, and the number of bits you can use in any unsigned integer type is always `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned_type)`.

Second, you can make the bit map (or ordered bit set) dynamically resizable, by adding the size information to the structure.

The above boils down to

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define ULONG_BITS (CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned long))

typedef struct {
    size_t         ulongs;
    unsigned long *ulong;
} bitset;

#define BITSET_INIT { 0, NULL }

void bitset_init(bitset *bset)
{
    if (bset) {
        bset->ulongs = 0;
        bset->ulong  = NULL;
    }
}

void bitset_free(bitset *bset)
{
    if (bset) {
        free(bset->ulong);
        bset->ulongs = 0;
        bset->ulong  = NULL;
    }
}

/* Returns: 0 if successfully set
           -1 if bs is NULL
           -2 if out of memory. */
int bitset_set(bitset *bset, const size_t bit)
{
    if (bset) {
        const size_t  i = bit / ULONG_BITS;

        /* Need to grow the bitset? */
        if (i >= bset->ulongs) {
            const size_t   ulongs = i + 1; /* Use better strategy! */
            unsigned long *ulong;
            size_t         n = bset->ulongs;

            ulong = realloc(bset->ulong, ulongs * sizeof bset->ulong[0]);
            if (!ulong)
                return -2;

            /* Update the structure to reflect the changes */
            bset->ulongs = ulongs;
            bset->ulong  = ulong;

            /* Clear the newly acquired part of the ulong array */
            while (n < ulongs)
                ulong[n++] = 0UL;
        }

        bset->ulong[i] |= 1UL << (bit % ULONG_BITS);

        return 0;
    } else
        return -1;
}

/* Returns: 0 if SET
            1 if UNSET
           -1 if outside the bitset */
int bitset_get(bitset *bset, const size_t bit)
{
    if (bset) {
        const size_t  i = bit / ULONG_BITS;

        if (i >= bset->ulongs)
            return -1;

        return !(bset->ulong[i] & (1UL << (bit % ULONG_BITS)));
    } else
        return -1;
}
```

In a `bitset` structure, the `ulong` is a dynamically allocated array of `ulongs` `unsigned long`s. Thus, it stores `ulongs * ULONG_BITS` bits.

`BITSET_INIT` is a preprocessor macro you can use to initialize an empty bitset. If you cannot or do not want to use it, you can use `bitset_init()` to initialize a bitset. The two are equivalent.

`bitset_free()` releases the dynamic memory allocated for the bitset. After the call, the bit set is gone, and the variable used is re-initialized. (Note that it is perfectly okay to call `bitset_free()` on an un-used but initialized bit set, because calling `free(NULL)` is perfectly safe and does nothing.)

Because the OS/kernel will automatically release all memory used by a program (except for certain types of shared memory segments), it is not necessary to call `bitset_free()` just before a program exits. But, if you use bit sets as part of some algorithm, it is obviously a good practice to release the memory no longer needed, so that the application can potentially run indefinitely without "leaking" (wasting) memory.

`bitset_set()` automatically grows the bit set when necessary, but only to as large as is needed. This is not necessarily a good reallocation policy: `malloc()`/`realloc()` etc. calls are relatively slow, and if you happen to call `bitset_set()` in increasing order (by increasing bit number), you end up calling `realloc()` for every `ULONG_BITS`. Instead, it is often a good idea to adjust the new size (`ulongs`) upwards -- the exact formula you use for this *is* your reallocation policy --, but suggesting a good policy would require practical testing with practical programs. The shown one works, and is quite robust, but may be a bit slow in some situations. (You'd need to use at least tens of thousands of bits, though.)

The `bitset_get()` function return value is funky, because I wanted the function to return a similar value for both *"unset"* and *"outside the bit set"*, because the two are logically similar. (That is, I consider the bit set, a set of set bits; in which case it is logical to think of all bits outside the set as unset.)

A much more traditional definition is

```
int bitset_get(bitset *bset, const size_t bit)
{
    if (bset) {
        const size_t  i = bit / ULONG_BITS;

        if (i >= bset->ulongs)
            return 0;

        return !!(bset->ulong[i] & (1UL << (bit % ULONG_BITS)));
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

which returns 1 only for bits set, and 0 for bits outside the set.

Note the `!!`. It is just two not operators, nothing too strange; making it a not-not operator. `!!x` is 0 if `x` is zero, and 1 if `x` is nonzero.

(A single not operator, `!x`, yields 1 if `x` is zero, and 0 if `x` is nonzero. Applying not twice yields the not-not I explained above.)

To use the above, try e.g.

```
int main(void)
{
    bitset train = BITSET_INIT;

    printf("bitset_get(&train, 5) = %d\n", bitset_get(&train, 5));

    if (bitset_set(&train, 5)) {
        printf("Oops; we ran out of memory.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else
        printf("Called bitset_set(&train, 5) successfully\n");

    printf("bitset_get(&train, 5) = %d\n");

    bitset_free(&train);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Because we do not make any assumptions about the hardware or system we are running (unless I goofed somewhere; if you notice I did, let me know in the comments so I can fix my goof!), and only stuff that the C standard says we can rely on, this should work on anything you can compile the code with a standards-compliant compiler. Windows, Linux, BSDs, old Unix, macOS, and others.

With some changes, it can be made to work on microcontrollers, even. I'm not sure if all development libraries have `realloc()`; even `malloc()` might not be available. Aside from that, on things like 32-bit ARMs this should work as-is just fine; on 8-bit AVRs and such it would be a good idea to use `unsigned char` and `CHAR_BIT`, instead, since they tend to emulate the larger types rather than supporting them in hardware. (The code above would work, but be slower than necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

The returned value from `bitset_lookup` should be treated as a binary truth value (i.e. yes on no), not a numerical value. If it's zero, the bit is not set; if it's not zero, the bit is set. Really that function should return `boolean != 0`, which would force it to a value of zero or one, a true boolean, not the current zero or anything (well actually `(1 << (item & MASK))`). C/C++ not having a true boolean can cause this sort of confusion.